# Escape password containing @ when using postgres pg_dump command

Tags: postgresql, shell

I 'm using postgres, I created db, user, password, this is the password:

password = `name&text@sob`

I'm using the following command to dump database and it works on my other databases I have:

`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner --dbname=postgresql://db_user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name`

But it doesn't work when using the DB with the password containing `&` and `@`:

`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner --dbname=postgresql://db_user:name&text@sob@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name`

doesn't work because of the `&` and `@` in the password- So I escaped the `&` with `\` but it didn't work for `@` - any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

adding `?password=name%26te‌​xt%40sob` as uri parameter should do:

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner --dbname=postgresql://db_user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?password=name%26te‌​xt%40sob
```

as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING

> Components of the hierarchical part of the URI can also be given as
>   parameters.

**update**

as Roko noticed, URL has to be [encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: My Password is elly@123i what should be the encoding- its not taking elly%40%31%32%33i...any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

You can encode the signs directly in the connection string, no need to bother with the extra URL parameter.

```
--dbname=postgresql://db_user:name%26te‌​xt%40sob@127.0.0.1:5432/db_nam‌​e
```

Comment: To encode it, use either a linux package [gridsite-clients](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urlencode), [w3 page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) or any other tool that a quick google search returns.